# What is this Season's Greetings sign for in March in India?

Tags: india, culture, identify-this, public-holidays, seasonal

While being driven from Dehli to Agra on March 17, 2014, I saw a number of seasons greetings signs, as shown in the following picture:

[image]

What holiday is this for? [Holi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holi)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, these were for the Indian festival 'Holi', the festival of colours. It is the one of the most important festival in India and is celebrated by playing with colours (people put variuos colours on each other, it is fun). Coincidently, March 17, 2014, your travel day was the day `Holi` fell in 2014 (The Indian festivals are mostly dependent on lunar calendar, due to which the dates keep changing every year).

Hope you too tried those colours. Even if you missed that, at least try the [Gujiya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujia) from a good sweet shop.